# jQuery, AJAX, & BoardGameGeek XML API

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

Okay, I edited my question to show where I am at : 
I have a javascript test code :

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1/sgbd/web/bgg_talk.php',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'text/xml',
  success: function() { alert("Success"); },
  error: function() { alert("Failed!"); }
});
```

And a PHP code running on the same server :

```
<?php
$xmlStringContents = file_get_contents('http://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/search?search=Carcassonne');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
echo($xmlStringContents);
?>
```

When I execute the PHP script I get the good XML page.
But when I execute the JS, I still get "Failed!".

Could someone tell me what is wrong ? Thanks!

Comment: It means your ajax call is failing every time.  Where are you running this?

Comment: maybe you'll find your answer here? [cross domain requests header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477527/cross-domain-ajax-request)

Comment: I just made a test web page with this script and nothing more except html headers. I am running it on localhost. (which is not www.boardgamegeek.com of course!)

Comment: @ho.s : from your answer, it appears that "Assumption 2: YOU are NOT in control of the pages on server"
implies that the only way to do what I want is to make a proxy ? really, there is no other way ?

Comment: all I know (.. doesn't have to be 100% true as of latest updates or "magic" :-)) is that server has to be configured (send allow-origin headers) to allow access. I had that issue during a job where we had the same problem. so just setting "crossDomain: true" on client side is not enough

Comment: Okay... So since I don't have access to the server, it won't work. But what is the point of making an open XML API then ?

Comment: sorry I'm not really into this API .. did you try to find an answer/help on the website itself? the problem is mentioned i.e. [here](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/99401/boardgamegeek-xml-api/page/47) ..

Comment: Mhh okay from your link I will try to make JS call a PHP script with the url to parse, and then get the data back from the PHP script. Seems ugly, but anyway I'll post it as an answer if it works.

Comment: `crossDomain: true,` doesn't actually do anything toward making a cross-domain request work, fyi.

Comment: Edited question with my current state

Comment: it turns out (tested on localhost myself) that you get http 200 OK (thats what still causes "error" due to the known issue, but already get the beloved result `success: function(xhr) { console.log("Success");},
error: function(xhr) { console.log("Failed!");},
complete: function(xhr) {console.log(xhr.responseXML,xhr.responseText)}`

Comment: Damn, okay XD So it is a bad idea to use error:, right ?