# Not able to call servlet using ajax

Tags: java, ajax, servlets

I am trying to call servlet using ajax on click event. And from that servlet I am calling google auth end point. I tried set header to the servlet I am calling but I an not able to get rid of this error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=2536-a…nid%20profile%20email&state=F1BFD3804&display=popup.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Here is the code

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/url-for-servlet",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                contentType:    'application/json',
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(jqXHR)
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("yippy");
                    console.log(data);

                }
            });
```

On servlet I added to response

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
```

Any idea what I am missing here? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Those headers need to be set by the target URL (accounts.google.com thus). The inability to do should already have implied that you're not allowed to do those things with the target service. Look for a different solution, usually based on their own API documentation. Your question is however strange as the error is not caused by the code posted so far. Perhaps you oversimplified/omitted too much?

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard security restriction : JS cannot make requests to domains other than their own. So you have an application on `localhost` making Ajax calls to an application on `accounts.google.com` - not allowed by default.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477527/cross-domain-ajax-request)

Answer (score 0):

AJAX usually doesn't allow to call other domain API from it. It is called CSRF attack. The solution for you is, Post the data to your server servlet and do the action required there in the backend(Servlet).