# how to make a contact from html form and php page by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I make this form to send data to a php page in another domain but always it results error. can someone explain my problem
I search in Internet many times but exactly I didnt find my answer
here is my code

html:

```
<form action="#" id="smail" method="post" class="form">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="Your Name *">
  <input type="text" name="mailadd" value="Your E-mail *">
  <textarea name="message" cols="0" rows="0">Your Message *</textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="send message">
</form>
```

js:

```
$('#smail').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var mail = $("#smail input[name=name]").val();
  var message = $("#smail input[name=mailadd]").val()+' '+$("#smail textarea[name=message]").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"http://cofeebeen.dx.am/email.php",
    crossDomain: true,
    data:{ 
      "mail": mail,
      "message": message, 
    },
    dataType: "text",
    error: function(){
      alert("error")
    }
  }).success(function(result){
      alert(result)
  });
});
```

php:

```
<?php
  $subject = $_POST["mail"];
  $msg = $_POST["message"];
  mail("someone@example.com",$subject,$msg);
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross domain ajax request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477527/cross-domain-ajax-request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP code is not correct, we can get data at your PHP page like below.

Correct code:

```
$subject = $_POST["mail"];
$msg = $_POST["message"]
```

Incorrect code:

```
$subject = $_POST["name"];
$msg = $_POST["mailadd"]
```

I hope it will work now.

Comment: Also please return some result from PHP page like echo the email result or  echo1 for success..but we must return something to ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Per @mpf82's comment, if this is a cross domain request, that changes things. However, the AJAX request is currently passing 2 PHP post variables:

```
...
data:{ 
  "mail": mail,
  "message": message, 
},
...
```

And you reference 3:

```
$_POST['name'];
$_POST['mailadd'];
$_POST['message'];
```

As @Reghbendra pointed out, you are referencing the incorrect variable names. Plus, since you did the concatenation of `mailadd` and `message` in Javascript, you can skip that part in PHP.

Therefore, your code would need to reference the two post variables that were passed by their proper indexes.

Result code:

```
﻿<?php
$subject = $_POST["mail"];
$msg = $_POST["message"];
mail("someone@example.com",$subject,$msg);
?>
```

You also should consider the headers for the PHP mail function to ensure that it sends properly and is handled correctly. See the documentation for the function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).